# Last six digits of $\left\lfloor\frac{302000002!}{e}\right\rfloor$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, derangements

> Find the ending 6 digits of $\left\lfloor\frac{302000002!}{e}\right\rfloor$

Things I’ve noticed:
The ending six digits of $302000002$ is just $2$.
It’s essentially $!302000002$ is one off from $\left\lfloor\frac{302000002!}{e}\right\rfloor$.

The number $302000002$ seems arbitrary, so I think I’m missing something crucial. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, for even $n$, 
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n!}{e}\right\rfloor=!n-1,$$
so it suffices to find the last six digits of $!n-1$ (as you noted). The second crucial step is that
$$!n=n!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{n!}{k!}.$$
The number $n=302000002$ becomes important because, for $k\leq 302000002-3,$
$$10^6\ \big|\ n-2\ \big|\ \frac{n!}{(n-3)!}\ \big|\ \frac{n!}{k!}.$$
So many of the terms have $10^6$ as a divisor. Can you finish the rest?

Comment: Much thanks! I'll take it from here.